# The command in the exe file does not work

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I have a python script running a command in the console. Everything works fine in the IDE, but after compiling it into an exe using pyinstaller (pyinstaller -F -i "C:\xampp\htdocs\organaizer\1.ico " websockets.py ) the command does not run. Error up VCRUNTIME140.dll' 14.12 is not compatible with this PHP build linked with 14.29 in Unknown on line 0. I notice that the window appears for a second and immediately disappears. I use Python 3.7. An example of a command that does not run in exe

```
import subprocess 
import os 
os.system('php artisan websockets:serve')
```

Tell me what the problem may be.

Comment: "14.12 is not compatible with this PHP build linked with 14.29": the error message shows your problem: incomptable versions. Perhaps you have two versions of PHP on your system. It doesn't look like it's even a python or pyinstaller problem.

Comment: To be honest, it's silly to have a single-line Python script converted to an exe to run a PHP script. Just run the PHP script directly, or use a Windows script, since you're using Windows.

Comment: What would you recommend to run this command on the command line?

Comment: Fix your library version problem first.

Comment: Does the command `php artisan websockets:serve` work for you on the command line, by itself? I expect not, in which case this is not a Python question at all.

Answer (score -1):

```py
import subprocess

subprocess.call(['php', 'artisan', 'websockets:serve'])
```

Comment: PHP Warning:  'C:\Users\A4F7~1\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI98162\VCRUNTIME140.dll' 14.12 is not compatible with this PHP build linked with 14.29 in Unknown on line 0

Comment: problem in your PHP Fix it and try again